# Independent t test or repeated measure anova

Tags: anova

A nurse manager is interested in determining whether there were statistically significant outcome measures between male and female patients measured at 3 different time points. Do I use an independent t test or repeated measure anova?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, please add the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework problem, so I will answer it like one.

Would you expect the measures from the same patient at 3 different time points to be correlated?  In other words, would knowing the value of the measurement at the first time point inform you what the value might be at the second time point?  What are the assumptions of each test?  Answering these questions will give you the answer.